# Python regex for finding everything inbetween two \n\n and \n\n

Tags: python, regex, wildcard

I have a large text string, with init there are several blocks that look very similar to this;

```
text = '\n\n(d)In the event of this happens a Fee 
of \xc2\xa32,000 gross, on each such occasion.\n\n'
```

using the code below I can find all instances of money:

```
import re
re.finall('\xa3(.*)', text)
```

but this only returns up to the comma `In the event of this happens a Fee of \xc2\xa32,000 gross` instead of the whole block, I'm hoping to return the block where the Unicode for British pounds `\xa3` is mentions

Comment: Why not just `'\n\n(.*)\n\n'`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh wouldn't that return every single text block in the text string? I was hoping of combing that with `'\xa3(.*)'`

Comment: `\n\n(.*\xa3.*)\n\n`

Comment: Interesting, that `\n\n(.*\xa3.*)\n\n` will work if there  is  only 1 line in between double `\n`s. Can there be 2 lines (that is, one linebreak) between the delimiters? Is that a linebreak right after `Fee` in the sample above? If yes, Daniel's regex [won't work](https://ideone.com/txNKU6).

Comment: @DanielLee as suggested it only works for 1 line in between double \n, through out the document there can be 2 or 3 line breaks between the delimiters

Comment: Try [`re.findall('\n\n((?:(?!\n\n|\xa3).)*\xa3.*?)\n\n', text, flags=re.S)`](https://ideone.com/txNKU6). As far as I understand, there can be 2 or 3 *non-consecutive* linebreaks between the delimiters, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this regular expression:

```
text = ('\n\nthis is not wanted\n\n'
        '(d)In the event of this happens a Fee\n'
        'of \xc2\xa32,000 gross, on each such occasion.\n\n'
        'another wanted line with pound: \xc2\xa31,000\n\n'
        'this is also not wanted\n\n')

re.findall(r'(?:.+\n)*.*\xa3(?:.+\n)*', text)
```

This will find all multiline blocks of non-empty lines which contain at least one `\xa3`.

As @wiktor-stribiżew pointed out in a comment, this only finds those blocks which have another character after the pound symbol; this seems to be what you want, so it is no problem, but it should be mentioned.

Comment: This `r'(?:.+\n)*.*\xa3(?:.+\n)*'` is a nice example of unrolling a pattern, but the second `+` quantifier won't let the pattern match the symbol at the end of a line inside the substring.

Comment: Right.  In this case it seems to be correct though.  OP expects something after the pound symbol (the number).  But worth mentioning, so thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import re 
text = '\n\nblock1\xa3block1.\n\nblock2\x80block2\n\nblock3\xa3block3\n\n' 
result= re.findall('.*\xa3.*', text) #capture only blocks containing pound symbol and discards block2 that contains euro 
print(result)
```

Comment: Sure, we tried. Have you? The original input is `text = '\n\n(d)In the event of this happens a Fee\n of \xc2\xa32,000 gross, on each such occasion.\n\n'`. Your regex does not return the part of string between double newline delimiters.